# Differentiability of $f(x)={x^2\sin{(\dfrac{1}{x})}}$ at $x=0$

Tags: limits, derivatives

I'm a bit confused here. When we take the derivative of 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
  x^2\sin{\biggl(\dfrac{1}{x}\biggr)}&x\neq0\\
  0 &x=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
It's derivative is not defined at $x=0$ as 
$f(x)=2x\sin{\biggl(\dfrac{1}{x}\biggr)}-\cos{\biggl(\dfrac{1}{x}\biggr)}$.

However, approaching this problem through the limit form of the derivative gives the value of the derivative at $x=0$:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
$$\implies f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{h^2\sin{\biggl(\dfrac{1}{x}\biggr)}-0}{h}=0$$

What I'm curious about here is why differentiating $f(x)$ first and then entering $x=0$ is failing in contrast to finding the derivative through limits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the first approach is that it invokes the product rule in a case where it is not applicable, as well as reversing a particular implication. What the product rule actually says is that **if** $g$ and $h$ are differentiable at $x$, then so is $gh$ and we can compute $(gh)'(x)$ via a formula.

In this case, $x^2$ is differentiable at $0$ while $\sin(1/x)$ is not. As such, the product rule is not applicable and we cannot use it to compute $(x^2 \sin(1/x))'(0)$.

Moreover, we *cannot* say that non-differentiability of $g$ or $h$ implies non-differentiability of the product. That would be a converse of the product rule, which (as you've observed) is false.

---

Note that I am assuming here that you've defined $f(0) = 0$; otherwise, $f$ fails to be differentiable there.

Comment: I've understood my mistake. Thanks, and yes, $f(x)=0$ at $x=0$ since this is the Volterra function.